# Serving static directories in CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to serve static files using CherryPy but I am unable to. I have looked in the tutorials but setting it up like that is also not working properly.

All this is using Python 3.4

**Config**

```
config = {
        '/ws': {
            'tools.websocket.on': True,
            'tools.websocket.handler_cls': ChatWebSocketHandler,
            'tools.websocket.protocols': ['toto', 'mytest', 'hithere']
        },
        '/assets': {
              'tools.staticdir.on': True,
              'tools.staticdir.dir': constants.TEMPLATE_PATH
        },
    }
```

I am starting up cherryPy like this

```
app_root = Root(args.host, args.port, args.ssl, ssl_port=args.ssl_port)
cherrypy.quickstart(app_root, '', config=config)
```

Constant Path is

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),"assets/")
```

I have tried using paths like `assets/`, `/assets/` as well instead of the above constant.

The thing is it does not recognize anyone of them and always gives a 404 error.

Comment: Your configuration as above should work. I have an almost identical one in one of my apps. You need to use an absolute path for tools.staticdir.dir - which you have. The only difference is that I use cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), "/", config), then cherrypy.engine.start(), then cherrypy.engine.block() instead of quickstart. Have you checked permissions are right?

Comment: This is also working in Python 2.7 for its 3 months left to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have had difficulty setting this up. I have a rather complicated setup complete with multiple subdomains that has evolve through several early versions of CherryPy which may no longer be valid, and I've not verified this will work in the simpler quickstart configuration you have here. However the key lines in a setup that actually works for me is to put the config lines below in the webservice object that you mount. I put the config dict that defines the static dir in the class definition before any resources. It looks to me like you've defined your static dir in the configuration dict rather of a specific resource rather than the object. So perhaps try in your hosted service object:

```
class WebService(object):
    _cp_config = {
                  'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                  'tools.staticdir.dir': '/path/to/serve/static/files/from'
                  }

    @cherrypy.expose
         def index(self):

   [ ...additional resource definitions, etc ...]
```

Then later on:

```
    my_cp_app = 
    cherrypy.tree.mount(subDomain.WebService(),
                        '/subdomainFileLocation',
                        subdomainConfigDict)

    cherrypy.quickstart(config=domainConfig)
```

I know you're working on Python 3. This above works for me on Python 2.7 + cherrypy-8.1.2. I hope this is helpful.